# How Spring Boot understand on what exactly custom object is need to map fields from html?

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring boot application:

Here repo:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import myproject.eshop.model.User;

// Use JPQL
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Here controller:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import myproject.eshop.model.Role;
import myproject.eshop.model.User;
import myproject.eshop.repo.UserRepository;

import java.util.Collections;
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @GetMapping("/registration.html")
    public String registration(Model model) {
        logger.info("open_registration.html");
        model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
        return "registration.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration.html")
    public String registartionNewUser(User user, Model model, @RequestParam(name = "retypePassword", required = true) String retypePassword) {
        logger.info("retypePassword = " + retypePassword + ", user = " + user);
        if (user.getUsername().trim().isEmpty()
                || user.getPassword().trim().isEmpty()
        ) {
            model.addAttribute("registrationError", "Аll fields are required!");
            return "registration.html";
        }
        user.setActive(true);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));
        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (userFromDb != null) {
            model.addAttribute("registrationError", "User already exist!");
            return "registration.html";
        }
        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/login.html";
    }
}
```

here template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${appName}">Template title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/public/style.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h2 align="center">Registration new user</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/registration.html}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <label for="retypePassword">Retype password</label>
        <input type="password" id="retypePassword" name="retypePassword"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Registration"/>
    </form>
    <p th:if="${registrationError}" th:text="${registrationError}" class="error"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my custom object `User`:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usr") // PostgreSQL not work with table "user"
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private boolean active;
    @NotNull
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

When open `registration.html` filled all fields and click **submit** button then call method `registartionNewUser`

And param `user` is correct filled (from form `registration.html`). 
How Spring Boot link form `registration.html` with my customer object `User` ?

In `registration.html` no link to my customer object `User`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're implemented hibernate or jpa in backend which handle this things for you.

Notice that you column names are same as your name which you pass by html.

So that they accept the requested object get individual variable and create empty object of User class and place on exect match in User entity class and this way create User object.

For cross verification change it to capital or something it gives an 400 error.

This process is not that much easy as we discuss. You modify this as your way using javax library annotations.

For more detail this link,
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate-tutorials/

Comment: But if I has another custom object e.g. .Category with same column name "username". How Spring understand that it must use column "username" exactly from object User, not object Category?

Comment: @a_subscriber In such case, you define Category entity object as param in register method and your controller mapping url is also according to that. Okay?

Comment: @a_subscriber in normal case json parser perfom this role like com.fasterxml.jackson

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried make use of @ModelAttribute annotation which will map your custom made
object User to a model attribute and then exposes it to a web view.

```
 <form th:action="@{/registration.html}" modelAttribute= "user" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" path = "username"  
        autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" path = "password"/>
    <label for="retypePassword">Retype password</label>
    <input type="password" id="retypePassword" name="retypePassword"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Registration"/>
</form>
```

And then you bind it in the controller class:

```
 @GetMapping( "/registration.html")
public String registration( @ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
    logger.info("open_registration.html");
    model.addAttribute("appName", appName);
    return "registration.html";
}
```

Comment: error: ')' expected
    @GetMapping(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, "/registration.html")

Comment: My apologies . I put the attribute in the wrong place by mistake. Should be a parameter in the method.